# Am I doing the right thing by removing inappropriate tags?

Tags: support, tags, edits

I keep seeing users tag questions with incorrect tags. For example, a lot of [apache](/questions/tagged/apache) questions are tagged with [php](/questions/tagged/php), but in reality have nothing to do with PHP. Although users browsing the [php](/questions/tagged/php) tag are likely to know the answer to these questions, am I doing the right thing by removing the incorrect tags?

Comment: Shotgunning tags is a common approach by low performing question askers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Although users browsing the PHP tag are likely to know the answer to these questions, am I doing the right thing by removing the incorrect tags?

Yes. Yes, you are.

Of course, be careful to make sure it was a mistake on the OP's part. But removing tags that don't have anything to do with the question is absolutely the right way to go. Sometimes, people will add incorrect tags just to increase the attention the question receives.

Comment: It is also a good idea to fix anything else you might see wrong with the question (typos, grammar, punctuation) since you're editing anyway